# Django, on registering a user: AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, attributes, registration, meta

On trying to register a new user using the wp_register (this is a different type of user), I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

There are various answers on this, but none solved my problem.

The system was working fine until I tried to add different views in for the different users (W and WP) I also added the field 'description' (as a test) to the registration form, and am also attempting to create two different profiles for two different users (WPs and Ws). I have created, as you will see below, a separate registration page for wps (user type2), referenced by profile_wp, register_WP etc as well, and on trying to register a user using this form, I receive the error referenced above.

The various relevant bits of my code are below

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm): #form that inherits from the usercreationform
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta: 
        model = User 




class Register_WP_Form(UserCreationForm): #form that inherits from the usercreationform
    email = forms.EmailField()
    description=forms.EmailField()
    #choice = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect(
    #attrs={'class': 'Radio'}), choices=(('option1','I am a W'),('option2','I am a WP'),))

    class Meta: 
        model = User 

        #when this form validates it creates a new user
        #type the fields to be shown on your form, in that order.
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2','description'] 





class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta: 
        model = User 
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Profile
        fields=['image']
```

views.py

```
#USERS (register) view.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages #this allows us flash messages for testing
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from .forms import UserUpdateForm
from .forms import Register_WP_Form
from .forms import ProfileUpdateForm

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.



def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        #this UserRegisterForm is created in forms.py and inherits from UserCreationForm (the ready made form)
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) #create a form that has the data that was in request.POST
        if form.is_valid(): #is the form valid (do you have a username like this already, passwords match?
            form.save()#this just saves the account, hashes the password and it's all done for you!
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account created for {username}, you can now login.')
            return redirect('socialmedia-moreinfo')

    else:
        form =UserRegisterForm() #if the form input is invalid, render the empty form again

    #above we are creating a blank form and rendering it to the template
    return render(request, 'users/register.html',{'form':form})
#different types of messages message . debug, inf success warning and error


def register_wp(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        #this UserRegisterForm is created in forms.py and inherits from UserCreationForm (the ready made form)
        form = Register_WP_Form(request.POST) #create a form that has the data that was in request.POST
        if form.is_valid(): #is the form valid (do you have a username like this already, passwords match?
            form.save()#this just saves the account, hashes the password and it's all done for you!
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account created for {username}, you can now login.')
            print("SUCCESS")
            return redirect('profile-wp')

    else:
        form =Register_WP_Form() #if the form input is invalid, render the empty form again

    #above we are creating a blank form and rendering it to the template
    return render(request, 'users/register-wp.html',{'form':form})
#different types of messages message . debug, inf success warning and error


def register_w(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        #this UserRegisterForm is created in forms.py and inherits from UserCreationForm (the ready made form)
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) #create a form that has the data that was in request.POST
        if form.is_valid(): #is the form valid (do you have a username like this already, passwords match?
            form.save()#this just saves the account, hashes the password and it's all done for you!
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account created for {username}, you can now login.')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        form =UserRegisterForm() #if the form input is invalid, render the empty form again

    #above we are creating a blank form and rendering it to the template
    return render(request, 'users/register-w.html',{'form':form})
#different types of messages message . debug, inf success warning and error





@login_required #this is a decorator (adds functionality to an existing function)
def profile(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request,f'Your account has been updated')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:   
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)


    context={
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }

    return render(request,'users/profile.html',context)
        #add a login required dectorator that django provides
        #we want a user to be logged in to view this profile view
        #see the very top to import decorators






def profile_wp(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request,f'Your account has been updated')
            return redirect('profile-wp')

    else:   
        u_form =UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form =ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)


    context={
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
        }

    return render(request,'users/profile-wp.html',context)
        #add a login required dectorator that django provides
        #we want a user to be logged in to view this profile view
        #see the very top to import decorators
```

urls.py

```
#URLS in main project directory

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views #add this for user views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_views


#now create paths for the user views (default django user views) below
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/',user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('register_wp/',user_views.register_wp, name='register_wp'),
    path('register_w/',user_views.register_w, name='register_w'),
    #path('socialmedia/',include('socialmedia.urls')),
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('profile/',user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile-wp/',user_views.profile_wp, name='profile-wp'),
    path('',include('socialmedia.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:#if we currently in DEBUG mode, then add the below to URL patterns
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: You've not included any code that references the use of `_meta`. You should add the code that causes the error

Comment: Thanks ....but Where and how?

Comment: The stacktrace with the error shows you exactly what code gets executed so you'll find the source there.